# Regex to find the first word in a string java without using the string name

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I am having a string which can have a sentence containing symbols and numbers and also the sentence can have different lengths

For Example

```
String myString = " () Huawei manufactures phones"
```

And the next time myString can have the following words

```
String myString = " * Audi has amazing cars &^"
```

How can i use regex to get the first word from the string so that the only word i get in the first myString is "Huawei" and the word i get on the second myString is Audi

Below is what i have tried but it fails when there is a space before the first words and symbols

```
String regexString = myString .replaceAll("\\s.*","")
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please post your attempts

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex with a capture group for matching:

```
^\W*\b(\w+).*
```

and replace with: `$1`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ho82Hx/1)

**Java Code:**

```
s = s.replaceAll("^\\W*\\b(\\w+).*", "$1");
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `\W*`: Match 0 or more non-word characters
- `\b`: Word boundary
- `(\w+)`: Match 1+ word characters and capture it in group #1
- `.*`: Match anything aftereards

Answer (score 0):

See how you get on with:

```
s = s.replaceAll("^[^\\p{Alpha}]*", "");
```

Comment: That would not leave only `Huawei` after the replacement. See https://ideone.com/RcjabW

Comment: Misread sorry. Confused by the fact this question was asked a couple of days ago with a slightly different requirement. Probably the same OP